# Install custom MessageProcessor in Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I've developed a custom message-processor.  Is it possible to install this such that it can be used in AnyPoint Studio's Flow GUI? 
ie. That it is included with all the other components in the list on the right of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you build it using DevKit: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Anypoint+Connector+DevKit

You can add custom processors to a module that can be packaged and installed into Studio.

Comment: I've read that and used it to build connectors but I can't seem to work out how to do it for other components besides connectors